# How to add a list to an object in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, webclient

I have this object class that has a list of customers as an attribute:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class PeopleDTO {

    private String processType;
    private String operation;
    private String entity;
    private String entityType;
    private Long id;
    private Document document;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    class Customer {
        private String systemId;
        private String customerId;
    }
    private List<Customer> customers;
}
```

This list is retrieved calling another microservice using webclient as follows:

```
public Mono<CuCoPerson> getCuCoPerson(Integer cucoId, String GS_AUTH_TOKEN) {
        WebClient webClient = WebClient.create();

        return webClient.get()
                .uri(GET_RELATION_BY_ID + cucoId)
                .header("Accept", "application/json")
                .header("Authorization", GS_AUTH_TOKEN)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(CuCoPerson.class)
                .map(cuCoPerson -> {
                    List<CustomerRelation> matches = cuCoPerson.getRelatedCustomers()
                            .stream()
                            .filter(relation -> relation.getSystemId().equals(400) || relation.getSystemId().equals(300) || relation.getSystemId().equals(410))
                            .filter(relation -> relation.getCustomerId().contains("F"))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
                    cuCoPerson.setRelatedCustomers(matches);
                    return cuCoPerson;
                });
    }
```

This method return a cucoPerson as follows:

```
{
    "id": 1,
        "relatedCustomers": [
            {
                "customerId": "xxx",
                "systemId": 999
            }
        ]
}
```

So now I want to add this object to my PeopleDTO class, but I don't know how. This is what I've done son far (hardcoded):

```
public PeopleDTO createPeople(Long id) {
        PeopleDTO people = new PeopleDTO();
        people.setProcessType("ONLINE");
        people.setOperation("UPDATE");
        people.setEntity("DOCUMENT");
        people.setEntityType("DOCUMENT");
        people.setIdCuco(id);
        people.setDocument(new Document());
        people.setCustomers(......);
    }
```

So as you can see I don't know how to add a Mono in the last line.

The expected result should be like this:

```
{
    "type": "ONLINE",
    "operation": "UPDATE",
    "id": 1,
    "entity": "DOCUMENT",
    "entityType": "NIE",
    "documents": {
        "id": 1,
        "additionals": {
            "issuing_authority": "Spain",
            "country_doc": "ES",
            "place_of_birth": "",
            "valid_from": "1995-08-09",
            "valid_to": "0001-01-01"
        },
        "code": "X12345",
        "typeDocument": "NIE"
    },
    "id": 1,
    "relatedCustomers": [
        {
            "customerId": "xxx",
            "systemId": 999
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You would need a way to convert the various objects in `relatedCustomers` into `Customer` objects, aggregating them to a list.

Comment: Yeah but I don't know hwo

Comment: What annotations are you using on the `PeopleDTO` object? With Spring, you should be able to perform this conversion automatically (I believe), without having to actually construct the objects yourself.

Comment: I've updated with the annotations over the PeopleDTO class

Comment: I'm not intimately familiar with Spring, but look into the `ConfigurationProperties` annotation for automatically processing your input into the java objects.

Answer (score 0):

first, create a list of customers like:

```
List<Customer> customers=new ArrayList<>;
```

Then add all the Customers to it one by one using a loop,
then you can directly add that to your object like

```
people.setCustomers(customers);
```

your object assignment should look something like:

```
public PeopleDTO createPeople(Long id) {
        PeopleDTO people = new PeopleDTO();
        people.setProcessType("ONLINE");
        people.setOperation("UPDATE");
        people.setEntity("DOCUMENT");
        people.setEntityType("DOCUMENT");
        people.setIdCuco(id);
        people.setDocument(new Document());

        List<Customer> customers=new ArrayList<>;
//add data to customer
        people.setCustomers(customers);
    }
```